# AssertConfigurationIsValid fires an Owin and AutoMapper error

Tags: automapper, structuremap, owin

I tried to use the new AssertConfigurationIsValid method in Structure Map 3 to validate my automapper configuration. I have:

```
  Strapper.Boot(x => {
    x.AddIoc();
  });
  ObjectFactory.Container.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

The AddIoc method has the following:

```
  ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => { x.AddRegistry(new IocRegistry()); });
  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new IocDependencyResolver(ObjectFactory.Container));
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new IocDependencyResolver(ObjectFactory.Container);
  FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.Single(x => x is FilterAttributeFilterProvider));
  FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new IocFilterProvider(ObjectFactory.Container));
```

Where the IocRegistry is the following:

```
  For<ConfigurationStore>().Singleton().Use<ConfigurationStore>().Ctor<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>>().Is("Mapper Registry", MapperRegistry.AllMappers);
  For<IConfigurationProvider>().Use(x => x.GetInstance<ConfigurationStore>());
  For<IConfiguration>().Use(x => x.GetInstance<ConfigurationStore>());     

  For<IOwinContext>().Transient().Use(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext());
  For<DbContext>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(() => new Context());

  Scan(x => {
    x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IOrderHandler<>));
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IOrderHandler<>));
    x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(OrderHandler<>)); //.OnAddedPluginTypes(y => y.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped());
    x.WithDefaultConventions();
  });

  Scan(x => {
    x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>));
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>));
    x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(QueryHandler<,>)); //.OnAddedPluginTypes(y => y.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped());
    x.WithDefaultConventions();
  });
```

I get 2 StructureMap building errors:

Result Message:
Test method AuditTests.Audit_Ioc_Valid threw exception:
StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException: StructureMap Failures:  2 Build/Configuration Failures and 0 Validation Errors

Profile 'DEFAULT'

---

Build Error on Instance 'AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore'
    for PluginType AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore
 - and Instance 'Lambda: IContext.GetInstance()' for PluginType AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider
 - and Instance 'Lambda: IContext.GetInstance()' for PluginType AutoMapper.IConfiguration

No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'AutoMapper.ITypeMapFactory'
There is no configuration specified for AutoMapper.ITypeMapFactory

---

Build Error on Instance 'Lambda: HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()'
    for PluginType Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext
 - and Instance 'Handlers.SignInUserHandler for PluginType Plug.IOrderHandler`1[Plug.Messages.SignInUserOrder]
Plug.OrderHandler`1[Plug.Messages.SignInUserOrder]

StructureMap.Building.StructureMapBuildException: Failure while building 'Lambda: HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()', check the inner exception for details
1.) Lambda: HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
2.) Instance of Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpContextExtensions.GetOwinEnvironment(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpContextExtensions.GetOwinContext(HttpContext context)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuildSession , IContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuildSession , IContext )
   at StructureMap.Building.BuildPlan.Build(IBuildSession session, IContext context) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Building\BuildPlan.cs:line 151
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.BuildNewInSession(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 108
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.NulloTransientCache.Get(Type pluginType, Instance instance, IBuildSession session) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Pipeline\NulloTransientCache.cs:line 28
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.ResolveFromLifecycle(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 102
   at StructureMap.SessionCache.GetObject(Type pluginType, Instance instance, ILifecycle lifecycle) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\SessionCache.cs:line 88
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.FindObject(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 198
   at StructureMap.Diagnostics.PipelineGraphValidator.tryBuildInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance, IPipelineGraph pipeline, ProfileReport report) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Diagnostics\PipelineGraphValidator.cs:line 82
Result StackTrace:
at StructureMap.Diagnostics.PipelineGraphValidator.AssertIsValid() in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Diagnostics\PipelineGraphValidator.cs:line 40
   at StructureMap.Diagnostics.PipelineGraphValidator.AssertNoErrors(IPipelineGraph graph) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Diagnostics\PipelineGraphValidator.cs:line 21
   at StructureMap.Container.AssertConfigurationIsValid() in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line 485

Any idea how to solve these 2 problems?

Thank You,
Miguel